# Is it possible to Animate a color change on multiple textblocks at once?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7, animation

I've to a Windows Phone 7 app with a page and a StackPanel on that page.

The StackPanel contains several TextBlock elements.

I need to animate the color of ALL the TextBlock elements the same way.

Unfortunately, when I set up a ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames, I can only specify a single TargetName. Since there are multiple TextBlock controls that need to be animated the same way, that's pretty inconvenient, and I suspect there has to be a better way to handle this that copy pasting n ColorAnimation definitions, one for each textblock to animate.

Any ideas how to set up a color animation to apply to multiple controls at once?

EDIT: I realize this is a WP7 question, but I've tagged it WPF, since I believe the same technique would apply to both, but feel free to correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You could also tag it XAML, given that's common to all three.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to target your animation at the property of a single element, then use ElementName binding to synchronize values between TextBlocks. or example:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="textOne" Text="One"/>
<TextBlock x:Name="textTwo" Text="Two"
           Background="{Binding Background, ElementName=textOne}"/>
```

In the above XAML the background of one `TextBlock` is bound to the other. If your storyboard targets 'textOne', then the other `TextBlock` will animate also.

Comment: Yep, just came across this related question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251122/same-animation-for-multiple-target-name  Just the answer I was looking for (even if it seems a tad roundabout). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would try to do this symmetrically, externalize the brush and use it in all respective places, something like this:

```
<StackPanel.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TBBackground" Color="White"/>
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource TBBackground}"/>
    </Style>
<StackPanel.Resources>
    <!- ... -->
    <Storyboard>
         <ColorAnimation Storyboard.Target="{StaticResource TBBackground}"
                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
                         To="Red"/>
    </Storyboard>
```

**Edit:** Tested it and there's some problem with immutability, possibly would need to wrap the colour otherwise, in Silverlight that may be connected with some trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Use a storyboard to change your textblock. You can style your textblocks with a storyboaed and then execute the storyboard when needed.